# enabled systemd service won't start on boot

Tags: systemd, services, daemon

I have 7 services enabled, 6 of them depend 1 the first one starting and it runs fine.
3 start fine and the other 3 won't start on boot but if I run **sudo systemctl start service** it runs fine.

Can you please help?

daemon

```
[Unit]
Description=SABnzbd Client
After=network.target openvpn@client.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=tatsu
Group=tatsu
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -OO /opt/SABnzbd/SABnzbd.py --browser 0 -s 192.168.0.227:8080
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-default.target
```

status

```
● sabnzbd.service - SABnzbd Client
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sabnzbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Status after Running **sudo systemctl start sabnzbd**

```
● sabnzbd.service - SABnzbd Client
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sabnzbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-11-16 09:07:50 GMT; 9s ago
 Main PID: 749 (python3)
    Tasks: 22 (limit: 1147)
   Memory: 61.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/sabnzbd.service
           └─749 /usr/bin/python3 -OO /opt/SABnzbd/SABnzbd.py --browser 0 -s 192.168.0.227:8080

Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,686::INFO::[SABnzbd:1427] Starting web-interface on 192.168.0.227:
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,687::INFO::[_cplogging:216] [16/Nov/2020:09:07:54] ENGINE Bus STAR
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,794::INFO::[_cplogging:216] [16/Nov/2020:09:07:54] ENGINE Serving 
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,795::INFO::[_cplogging:216] [16/Nov/2020:09:07:54] ENGINE Bus STAR
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,796::INFO::[SABnzbd:1464] Starting SABnzbd.py-3.1.1
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,807::INFO::[dirscanner:117] Dirscanner starting up
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,813::INFO::[urlgrabber:96] URLGrabber starting up
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,813::INFO::[notifier:122] Sending notification: SABnzbd - SABnzbd 
Nov 16 09:07:54 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:54,836::INFO::[postproc:232] Completed Download Folder /downloads/com
Nov 16 09:07:55 tatsu-dl python3[749]: 2020-11-16 09:07:55,269::INFO::[zconfig:71] No Bonjour/ZeroConfig support installed
```

the other 3 are the same for their respective applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your install section:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-default.target
```

`multi-default.target` isn't a thing.  [systemd.special(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html) lists the targets you can depend on.  You should either use `default.target` if this is part of the `--user` bus, or `multi-user.target` if this is part of the system bus.  It looks like you are using the system bus.

First use `systemctl disable <service>` to delete the symbolic link to `multi-default.target`, then change your install section to:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then `systemctl daemon-reload` to load the changes and use `systemctl enable <service>` again.